# df.describe() drops two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have been trying to summarize a data set. I tried using `df.describe()`  on the following dataset:

```
                                Lon        Lat swh_ku wind_speed_alt  rain_flag
Date                                                                          
2010-04-01 16:46:13.006 -79.092939  19.957745  1.223           8.43          0
2010-04-01 16:46:14.026 -79.072228  19.908426  1.307           8.54          0
2010-04-01 16:46:15.046 -79.051533  19.859103  1.339           8.16          0
2010-04-01 16:46:16.066 -79.030853  19.809776  1.448           8.45          0
2010-04-01 16:46:17.087 -79.010188  19.760445  1.393           8.67          0
```

However the results only reflect 3  out of the 5 columns.

Comment: By default it is for numeric columns, so try `df.describe(include='all')` and see `df.dtypes`

Comment: the resulti is not showing any result from the mean to the max for the swh_ku and wind_speed_alt columns.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make sure all your columns are numerical. Before using `describe()`, do this:

```
df.swh_ku = df.swh.ku.astype(float)
df.wind_speed_alt = df.wind_speed_alt.astype(float)
```

Comment: I got the following error `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'N\A'
`

Comment: @renardo That probably explains why describe doesn't work in the first place. You've got to decide how to handle missing values and then use the `df.fillna( your_new_value, inplace=True)`. I didn't just do this with an arbitrary zero because then 0s will be part of your `describe()` calculations